# Question about Knowledge Representation exercises

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm doing a Knowledge Representation exercise. I'm not sure about my solution.

EXERCISE:

*Doing physical activity makes people happy. Not doing physical activity makes people relaxed. Relaxed people are happy.*

Define a vocabulary and suitably represent the above description as first-order formulas.

Vocabulary: 
**people(x)** 
**PA(x)** (x do physical activity)
**happy(x)** (x is happy)
**relaxed(x)** (x is relaxed)

> for each(x) ((**people(x)**->**PA(x)**)->**happy(x)**)

> for each(x) ((**people(x)**->**not(PA(x))**)->**relaxed(x)**)

> for each(x) ((**people(x)**->**relaxed(x)**)->**happy(x)**)

thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You would not normally have a second implication, but use conjunctions instead.
The first one I would express as:

- `for each(x) (people(x) & PA(x) -> happy(x))`

So, for every X, if X is a person and X does physical exercise, then it follows that X is happy.

- `for each(x) (people(x) & !PA(x) -> relaxed(x))`

Same principle.

- `for each(x) (people(x) & relaxed(x) -> happy(x))`

If X is a person and X is relaxed, then X is happy.